# Are wordpress cron jobs executed sequentially or in parallel?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am trying to limit the number of emails sent from my website to cope with the hosting service email limitations.
I am using cron jobs and an indicator of piling the emails in the database to check if the number of emails sent is approaching the limit of max emails sent.

The way I do that, is by directly executing the scheduled process then make it 'sleep' for a certain period of time (according to its position in the queue) and then send the email and log in the database. 
To explain further the reason why I am using scheduled tasks and 'sleep', consider the scenario below:

1. A user tries to register to my website and expects an email to be sent to him/her shortly. Thus, if the emails/minute quota is exceeded, I need to send a different message: "Our server is busy, please permit 'x' minutes to perform the required task".
2. The requests to send email are all done through AJAX. Using 'sleep' within the process itself is not an option because the user will have to wait the x minutes until the 'busy message' is echo'd.
3. I tried with ob_flush, flush...etc. combinations to echo the message then the server works out everything in the background, but that never worked. The AJAX call was always waiting for the script to end to echo the result.
4. I need multi-threading in the single-threaded PHP language! As a workaround I used cron jobs, where each piled email is scheduled to be executed at `time()` (i.e. directly fire the scheduled job) which is hooked to the same function that sends emails. Using a flag, the function knows that the request is a piled email and makes it 'sleep' until the time required for the email quota reset.
5. The problem: If 5 people registered at almost the same time (while we still have an email pile), then we have 5 cron jobs that should all be executed at the same time and then sleep for a while (the sleep time can differ if the number of emails in the pile are already greater than the email quota), then emails are sent. However, when I check the logs in the database, I find that the scheduled jobs are executed sequentially and not in parallel. Sometimes it happens a cron job is fired before the other ends, but they don't fire at the same time.

I know that wordpress cron jobs are not really cron jobs and are fired once somebody visits the website (and I make sure I refresh the pages after the registration requests are sent to fire all of the scheduled tasks),  but they seem to be the only option for me since my hosting server doesn't allow access to the server neither allows scheduling cron jobs.

Here is part of the code that executes the above:

```
//Test example to pile up emails, where quota is set to 2 emails every 30 seconds
$Emails_Threshold = 2;
$Threshold_Duration = 0.5*60;
//Get email indicator info
$Email_Info = $wpdb->get_row( 
"SELECT * 
FROM PileEmails 
WHERE priority = -1 
AND Status='New';"
,ARRAY_A);

if ($sleep ==0 && $Queue_Info_id==0){ //Not a scheduled event
   //Check if there are queued emails
   $Queue_exist = $wpdb->get_row (
    $wpdb->prepare("
                    SELECT Status 
                    FROM PileEmails
                    WHERE Status='Queued';"
                    ,$mail_priority)
                ,ARRAY_A);
  if (!empty($Queue_exist) || ($Email_Info['last_email_time']   > (time()-$Threshold_Duration))){
    if ($Email_Info['count_emails']>=$Emails_Threshold){
           //Code to Pile up
    }
  }else{ 
   //Reset email counter
  }
}else{ 
$wpdb->insert( "PileEmails",$Sleep_Info,$format);
sleep(10); //10 seconds here just as an example
}
//Code to send emails
```

Here is what I get logged into the database when I try to send 10 emails after exceeding the quota.

[image: MYSQL database logs]

Notice that the time stamp has 10 seconds difference between each log and the following one although they should all be fired at the same time and each sleeps for 10 seconds then all send emails in parallel.

So my question is: Why does wordpress cron fire the scheduled jobs sequentially and not in parallel? and how to overcome this problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps I should point out a wordpress problem that I faced while compiling the code above:
When you make a wordpress cron job "sleep" that means it will be executed AGAIN whenever somebody visits your website during the time it sleeps...i.e. if the scheduled task is not finished, wordpress will re-fire it again because it still sees the cron job. 
I think this is something the wordpress guys should fix, nobody expects a cron job to be executed more than once at very close intervals.

Comment: Apparently what wordpress says on their website:"Note that scheduling an event to occur before 10 minutes after an existing event of the same name will be ignored, unless you pass unique values for $args to each scheduled event. " means that wordpress does not allow "Scheduling"  the same script more than once within a 10 min span while it should also  prevent "Executing" the same scheduled script more than once within a certain time span as well.

Comment: I would recommend first installing a cron management plugin so you can easily see when and if which crons are firing, or see here to create your own https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/simple-testing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, installing a cron plugin will help to manage your crons.

To answer your question, Wordpress uses a "cron lock" `defined('DOING_CRON')` and sets a transient `$lock = get_transient('doing_cron')` when the `spawn_cron` method is invoked.

So, if you have a look at `wp-includes/cron.php` you'll see Wordpress crons do not run concurrently by default and will not run more than once every 60 seconds.

```
// don't run if another process is currently running it or more than once every 60 sec.
    if ( $lock + WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT > $gmt_time )
        return;
```

Comment: Interesting!
So basically if I change the cron.php code, I should be able to get the cron jobs to be fired concurrently. I do use a cron management plugin, and it does show that all cron jobs are running (although only one is actually running)

Comment: I believe so, my initial thoughts would be to clone WP's native cron methods and hack on them some :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can only send one or two emails at a time this is going to be tricky to solve. An easier way to solve this would probably be to have WordPress use an SMTP email server that allows the frequency of emails you need to send. Just adding a new email account on your current hosting provider might suffice. If you do not know how to set that up manually there are plugins that will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....The "2 email threshold" in the code is just an example...The threshold is around 20 emails every 5 minutes....Yes it is of course possible to use other SMTP servers that allow a higher frequency of emails to be sent....but that is just avoiding the problem...I am mainly asking to know how the wordpress cron behaves and I am using the email problem as a study case.

Comment: Hi! Sorry if you think I avoided your question. If you have so many registrations that you have to que the emails you should also be having so many visits that you can rely on wp-cron running more or less constantly. I would just set up a cron job to run like every minute and then select the 2 most recent emails, send them and then set a flag on them to indicate they were sent. Of course if you have no visits to your site for several hours emails may get delayed then. But that will be the case with any type of queuing if you are using wp cron.

Answer (score 0):

As php runs from top to bottom so when you schedule a event using wordpress schedule event function, as below :

```
if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_hourly_event' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
}


add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
}
```

This function `do_this_hourly()` will run as per the schedule , but the code which you will write inside that function will run one by one only.

1. Let us take example of email sending to 5 persons, so the email will be sent to them one by one in a loop.
2. The time-stamp is entered by the insert query which you are using, there is no connection between the `timestamp` and the `mail sent time`, this timestamp you have created for your own logs , so that you can check.

There would be some difference for sure i:e 10 seconds, it can also be less or greater, depending on the time which server is taking to send email and process the insert query.

Each query will be fired and the timestamp will be inserted according to the time at that moment (server time).